# ¿Cómo puedo crear una barra de búsqueda similar a esta?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

me encuentro creando una página de comercio online y quería implementar una barra de búsqueda similar a la siguiente donde listar los productos que oferto. ¿Cómo podría desarrollar una solución similar a la encontrada en esta página?

Objetivo: https://dribbble.com/shots/8064813-Search-results

Comment: Esa barra de búsqueda usa animaciones. Puedes logarlo con librerías como [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/). Si usas React, la mejor que yo he usado es [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me parece que ya existen plugins que ayudan a desarrollar la barra de búsqueda como la que buscas, con jQuery puedes usar el autocomplete para lograr algo como eso ([Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/))
pero si lo quieres hacer desde cero, me parece que necesitas algunos componentes:

- Input de texto para que te puedas poner la búsqueda
- Una función que detecte los cambio en el input anterior
- Una función que haga peticiones http al servidor que regrese los resultados de la búsqueda (JavaScript puro, JQuery, o algún Freamwork de JavaScript)
- Dibujar en el Dom los que necesites mostrar.

En rasgos simples esos serian los pasos.